# Is it a vim plugin to jump between found patterns?

Tags: vim, plugins, editor

[Here on the video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&list=PLP6DbQBkn9ymGQh2qpk9ImLHdSH5T7yw7&v=rzMrBIVuxgM#t=223s) you can see a feature of jumping between found patterns. The algorithm is really different from vim default behavior.

Using vim you can find some pattern `/pattern<CR>` and jump to next `n` or to previous `N`. The disadvantage is: you should jump many-many-many times to get to proper position or write long pattern to reduce hits amount. Yes, you can apply something like `10n` to jump over next 10 hits but it is also inconvenient because you can not count large amount of hits at first glance.

In the video you see a better approach: text editor gives a short name to each hit so you can jump in two or three keystrokes.

I do not believe that nobody implemented the feature as a vim plugin but I failed to find something relative. Is it such plugin anywhere? May be something even better is implemented?

Comment: What I see in the video is that the matches are just being highlightet, or am I missing something? If you want that you can do `:set hlsearch`, see http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_all_search_pattern_matches

Comment: Pause video exactly at 3:43 please. You will see that every match is not simply highlighted but given a name (`A` `B` `C` ...). Then you type the name (e.g. press `B`) and jump directly to the match named `B`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haha.

The very first implementation of that idea was AFAIK a Vim plugin ([PreciseJump](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3437)), with the second implementation being another Vim plugin ([EasyMotion](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3526)) that got a lot more traction than the first and itself spawned many other implementations in many other contexts (editors, browsers…).

Comment: @FUT : EasyMotion actually helps you to move quickly anywhere in the buffer, and not necessarily link to search patter, it is *very* useful.

Comment: @XavierT. anywhere on the screen, I would say.

Comment: Yeah, it does really awesome things. Thank you folks!